# file_entity update means views now checks for public: in their uri?

Tags: 7, views, files

Since a recent update, I think Views must have changed the way it links in relationships to file fields.

Now the SQL includes a WHERE clause like this:

```
EXISTS (
  SELECT fm_access.fid AS fid
  FROM file_managed fm_access
  WHERE ( (fm_access.uri LIKE 'public%' ESCAPE '\\') ) AND
  (file_managed_field_data_field_file_private.fid = fm_access.fid) )
```

Now the files that are linked here are actually private, so this clause means my view now returns nothing.

Why is Views adding this bit, and how can I stop it from doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File entity adds a tag to Views' queries called `query_file_access`.

This checks to see if a user has `view private files` privilege, and if not it denies access to any private files.

So you can get this view working again by granting this privilege to that user.

I find the privilege confusing because I do not want grant access to all files to this user, and the privilege screen warns that this has security implications.

I believe it's ok as long as the node access checks are done.